# Calcular el costo de producción, la medida es mililitros y litros?

Tags: formulas, libreoffice-calc

### como puedo desarrollar esta fórmula en LibreOffice ?

Problema:
obtener el costo de producción de un líquido, donde puedas obtener el costo por litro, mililitro, o litro y fracción ( litro, mililitro )

esta es una captura de pantalla de mi idea basica de como debo hacerlo, pero me quede atorado en el punto donde debo poder ingresar la cantidad ya sea por entero o, fracción, y/o Entero y Fracción.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en este ejemplo si multiplicas por 0.200 solo obtengo una cantidad errónea con 2 ceros de mas en los decimales, y he ahí donde radica ya mi falta de práctica.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
si multiplico por 200, obtengo una cantidad correcta, sin embargo deberia poder representar esa cantidad como 0.200 al ser una fracción o 1.800 si es una cantidad con entero y fracción.

consejos o comentarios me seran muy utiles gracias...!!!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tenés es que estás confundiendo las unidades de medida.
Te sugiero que las agregues a las celda de cabecera para no perder de vista lo que estás haciendo.

La celda de porción la estas multiplicando por el precio por mililitro. Entonces 0.200 es 0.200 mililitros, no 200 mililitros (o 0.200 litros) que es lo que realmente estás queriendo multiplicar.

```
Precio por 1.8 litros: $27.5
1.8 l = 1.8 l * 1000 ml/l = 1800 ml
Precio por 1800 ml = $27.5
Precio por 1 l = $27.5 / 1.8 l = $15.27 /l
Precio por 1 ml = $27.5 / 1800 ml = $0.0153 /ml

Procion 200 ml = 0.2 l

Precio 200 ml = $0.0153 /ml * 200 ml = $3.055
Precio 0.2 l = $15.27 /l * 0.2 l = $3.055
```